# How can i return an object pointed to by an abstract class pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, abstract-class, abstraction

So to summarize I have something equivalent to

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    B(){};
    void foo() const override{
        //some code
    };
};

class C{
public:
    C(){};
    B someFunction();
private:
    A* x;
};
```

and `A* x;` points to some `B` object and I need `someFuntion()` to return that object that x is pointing to. I've tried just doing `return *x` but that doesn't work.

Comment: May I ask why you return a value of type `B` instead of `B*` or `B&`? Like this, it will be a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You must down-cast the `x` into `B` before de-reference.

```
class C
{
public:
   C() {};
   B someFunction()
   {
      return *static_cast<B*>(x); // like this
   }
private:
   A* x = new B;
};
```

You need also provide the `virtual ~A()`, not to have undefined behavior.
[When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

```
class A 
{
public:
   virtual void foo() const = 0;
   virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that `x` points to a `B` object then cast it first.

```
return *static_cast<B*>(x);
```